# Performing a Trasform that takes as input all the couple of items in a PCollection

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm doing some Machine Learning pre-computations using Dataflow. My problem is that I have a data set (say, an array of points in a highly dimensional vector space) in a PCollection `data` and I want to compute all pairwise distances. I'm trying to figure out a way of performing some operations on couples inside a PCollection, up until now I've figured out the following:

If I also had all the data in a single array `data_array=[x_1,...,x_n]` I think it could be done by launching a transform for all elements of `data_array` as in

```
([ data | myTransformHere(point) for point in data_array ]
        | <more code> )
```

(I'm not sure if it works, but I found similar syntax inside the code of `CoGroupByKey`)

Now the problem is that I have to produce the array `data_array` from the PCollection `data`. I can combine everything using

```
pdict = data | beam.transforms.combiners.ToDict()
```

and now pdict only has a single element which is a dictionary from which I could easily produce the array.

However, I don't know how to load the single value of pdict into memory in order to spawn more transforms. My I should do a `ParDo` and let it handle the spawning of the transforms (I know in advance the size of data_array, so the number of transforms to use is known in advance). But I'm not really sure how to do it.

Any suggestions? Maybe there is a standard way of doing complex operations on multiple PCollections at the same time?

UPDATE: I've found a way around the problem: I output each data element as a side output of a beam.Map and then each of these outputs gets passed as a side input (AsSingleton) to a Transform that takes as main input the original data and computes the distance between each point of the original data and the side input.

However, by looking at the performances I think that this is kind of suboptimal, since it's been computing for more than 23 hours of total workers time while the operation is highly parallelizable (the only real cost being memory). Maybe it was wrong to output singletons and pass them as side inputs?

Comment: The solution in your update is a reasonable option. There are other options, but this is the simplest one. Do you have a job ID so I can take a look why it's being slow? Also, how many elements are in that job, and how much total worker time do you expect it to take (instead of 23 hours), based on the performance of the DoFn's you're applying to the result?

Comment: @jkff thanks for the offer, but eventually the process failed and I would like to investigate it before wasting your time. Still, I am surprised that it takes so much because if I do the same operation serially on my low-end machine it takes less than a couple of hours to perform. I don't know exactly which part of the graph is wasting time and don't really know how to test it.

Comment: Hmm, it is surprising that processing the same amount of data with the same code would be so much faster serially than in parallel on the Dataflow service. That sounds like a bug and we'd definitely like to fix it, so a job ID would help with that. Also, does it work using the local runner and does it perform acceptably in that case?

Comment: @jkff Here is the job ID of the failed attempt:  2016-10-30_07_38_23-6868562757472632469, however I should point out that this job was NOT using the same code I used to perform the computation serially (on my machine).

If it could be useful, I'm doing a comparison by running the same code this time both on my machine and on the cloud, this is the job ID 2016-10-31_03_05_16-7080813269237891181 (the job completed in 1m48s on my machine, whilst is still running on the cloud)

Comment: Actually the correct job is  2016-10-31_03_23_46-7207164701682230486

Comment: Hmm, based on what I see in our logs, the shape of the pipeline is not quite what I thought it would be. Any chance you could upload the code (or an anonymized/stripped-down version) somewhere, so we can better understand what exactly it is doing?

Comment: The code I'm running is this one https://github.com/Enucatl/machine-learning-aging-brains/blob/distance-matrix/test_stuff.py, options in the Rakefile are those passed with `run:mycloud`

Comment: Hmm, is that the complete code? I don't see where filter_points and distance_from are defined.

Comment: Sorry, I proceded to add the module, they are defined in `agingbrains/transforms.py`

Comment: Oh I see! It seems like you're creating 1 PCollection per data item and also basically reprocessing the whole dataset N times using N filters of the form "is this item number i?". This is algorithmically inefficient. You can do something much simpler: pass the collection whose pairs you want to compute to the distance transform, both as a main input (to be parallelized over) and as a side input (so that it's accessible in full when processing each individual item). Something like this: https://gist.github.com/jkff/787efa00d6d0be94ea131f5037eaefe2